# What would be the best approach to updating a list in ReactJS after adding of a new list element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

let's say I'm making a todo list app with React, which lets user log in, create his own todo list and perform CRUD operations on it.

I see two approaches there:

1. When entering a page with todo list component, list items are fetched from the database (through backend .API for example) and saved in component state. Then, after performing some kind of operation - for example adding of a new  item to the list - POST request containing new item is made to the API and if succeeded, next item is simply added to component state, without any new GET to the API - changes are stored just in react state, until we refresh the page - after each site refresh new GET request is made to the API,  and whole, updated list is retrieved and saved in the state too.
2. When entering a page with todo list component, list items are fetched from the database and displayed (maybe even without saving them to the component state?). 
   Then, after performing some kind of operation - for example adding of an item to the list - POST request containing new item is made to the API and if succeeded , new GET request for the whole todo list data is made, and whole todo list gets refreshed.

Which approach would be better? I'm currently using the first one,  because setState is generally working faster than new GET to the API.  And I feel like it's a lot easier to maneuvre the data saved in the state.

But my fear is that if that todo-list would get really big, and whole data would be saved in react state, app would start running slow. On the other hand, getting whole list after each update would be slower too in that case.

Im not storing any sensitive (user password or sth) data in the state. Im storing just session Id in a cookie (what isn't probably the best solution right now too, but im still learning).

So again, which approach is better? Or maybe there is some kind of better, industry- standard way of doing this kind of things?

I would be grateful for any help.
Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your requirements. The first approach would work until you need server side pagination or filtering.

Comment: "Which way is better" is pretty opinion-based.  But if no other system is simultaneously changing the same data then I don't see why one would want to repeatedly transfer the same data over and over.  Though if the data sets are large (how large?) and the client shouldn't have the entire data set then any sort of server-side sorting/paging/filtering would necessitate the back-and-forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When entering a page with todo list component, fetch the todo list
>   items from the database and save in component state, and also display
>   the list to the user, they may want to edit (not just add a new todo
>   item).
>
> Then, after performing some kind of operation - for example adding of
>   a new item to the list - POST request containing new item is made to
>   the API and if succeeded, next item is simply added to component
>   state, without any new GET to the API - changes are stored just in
>   react state, until we refresh the page - after each site refresh new
>   GET request is made to the API, and whole, updated list is retrieved
>   and saved in the state too.

I have simply copied your first approach, the second work doesn't scale and doesn't make sense either...and nobody does that.

Anyway, i hope you got your answer, but always aim to reduce the number of requests to your server, and also reduce the payload of the request and response where you can and where it makes sense too.